# Netty to parse file stream?

Tags: java, netty, java-7

I have a requirement that two specific processes on the same host communicate through an append-only file. One process produces, the other consumes. The object-stream **must** hit the disk before going to the second process (at least the OS cache of the disk).

I would like to use Netty to parse the object-stream in the file. Is there a way to attach Netty to the file?

For latency sake, **I would rather that it didn't involve a timer.** Blocking is okay.

(I'm using JDK-7 if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 1):

There are some new features in Java 7 that you may find useful:

- By passing [APPEND](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#APPEND) as parameter to the
  [Files.newOutputStream(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newOutputStream%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29) you can write to an existing file.
- Another addition is the [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) which can be used to listen
  for event changes in a library as described in [Oracle's Java
  Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

Comment: you can append a file in jdk 6 using `FileOutputStream(file, true)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, on my mac WatchService appears to poll every 10 seconds. I haven't tried it out on a Linux box yet, but this is still very discouraging.

Comment: I've finally been able to try this on my linux box, and it appears to use inotify. Very encouraging.

Answer (score 0):

Netty is for socket. I guess Apache Camel is more suitable if you need to use file:

- http://camel.apache.org/
- http://camel.apache.org/file2.html
- http://camel.apache.org/stream.html

Comment: Camel's documentation says **Avoid reading files currently being written by another application**: http://camel.apache.org/file2.html